# Particle system collision with itself and other objects

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I'm trying to make a scene where some particles shoot up from a phone and then land on the table the phone is on, i can make them shoot up and bounce off the table well but when they land they seem to half clip though the table as shown in the image, are there certain things i should check to get me to the right solution, eg, im not sure if the instanced objects rigid body settings matter etc.

Also is there any way to make instance particle system objects collide with themselves?

[image]

Comment: Particles use simplified physics and boundary checks. Yes, you can make particles collide with each other, but whey will collide using spherical shapes. Consider looking at more precise rigid body simulations

Comment: or use molecular add-on....but for that few coins....i think Crantisz is right - this can do rigid body simulation easily

Comment: there are going to be a lot more coins i was just testing it before hand with a value that is easier to manage. i will look into the molecular addon. in the meantime i have read that enabling "Size Deflect" can help get better collisions on particle systems but whenever i enable this it just makes the coins float quite a bit over the surface i want it to land on, any ideas why this might be happening? for context the coins are about 5.38cm not sure if this size is too small for decent physics sims.

Answer (score 1):

Here a small example with rigid bodies...which is pretty fast with Blender and easy to handle.

Some values which are important:

- friction
- bounciness
- collision margin (set to 0)

might be as well a good idea to use some forces to "optimize" the falling behaviour.

[image]